# Capybara open an html file in my computer

Tags: testing, cucumber, capybara, bdd

I have an html file in my computer and I want to open that file using Capybara to test it. Could you help me to solve this problem?

P/S: That html file is created automatically in my app. I do appreciate any idea helping me to solve this problem. Thanks :)

**UPDATE:**
Based on the capybara source code [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/02aee989a992b8d19fb8d8b728b234d7d3c00b78/lib/capybara/session.rb), I found that I should use Capybara.current_session.driver.visit instead of page.visit. The problem is solved

Comment: You should answer your own question, so that its clear that you have an answer for people who are browsing through questions.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that the update to the question works (assuming the file is in the current directory):

```
filename = 'foo.html'
Capybara.current_session.driver.visit filename
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is located at `/path/to/folder/file.html`

Set `Capybara.app` to a folder containing this file:

```
Capybara.app = Rack::File.new('/path/to/folder')
```

and then

```
visit 'file.html'
```

should work for you

See also [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jgwhite/4046511) for example

Answer (score 0):

With simple relative file path I got errors:

```
Failure/Error: visit 'foo.html'
 
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidArgumentError:
   invalid argument
```

I didn't want to switch `Capybara.app` to `Rack::File` and back, so I've tried this way and it works:

```rb
visit "file://#{__dir__}/foo.html"
```