# Can I override Capybara's page.body value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I've run into an issue where stubbing a response is not working (using docker with remote browser), but need to test against an external request

Is there any way to just hardcode the response via Capybara?

```
# This is what we would normally do
WebMock.stub_request(:get, 'http://example.com').to_return(status: 200, body: IO.read('spec/factories/submission_stubs/mystub.html'))

# In theory this should return mystub.html, but that is not working in my case.
# But since we're using a remote webdriver via docker it has no idea about my 'mock'
visit 'http://example.com'

# So I'm looking to simply override page.body to be `mystub.html`
puts page.body
```

I also just attempted to read the straight file from this answer: [Capybara open an html file in my computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674013/capybara-open-an-html-file-in-my-computer)

But it appears that that file is not correctly being mounted on my remote driver's system

Edit: I could not for the life of me get this working as expected. The response was always returning and empty HTML page. My solution was to simply load my stubbed response into the cloud and make it public so that my remote browser could hit it.

Comment: If you were to post some code that shows the issue it would help us all greatly.

Comment: @engineersmnky edited

Comment: I would highly recommend the [`vcr`](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) gem in this case. It will allow you to wrap and mock essentially any web request made inside the `use_cassette` block

Comment: The issue though is that this is a remote browser, so it has no idea that the cassette exists. It's the same thing as me asking you to open localhost and tell me how to fix my css

Comment: I am not sure I understand. `capybara` is a testing framework, the cassettes are recordings of a web request, wrap a cassette around the web request and it is stubbed. Are you trying to use `capybara` for something else? Please post a more complete example maybe that is the issue

Comment: The issue again is that I'm using `Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, browser: :remote, url: 'webdriver:3000'`, but that webdriver is running as its own docker instance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you were referring is correct.
the trick here we load the path up till the directory where the file exist. Don't include the file name itself

Here is a working example:

```
context 'testing' do

  before do
    # the trick here we load the path up till the directory where the file exist
    # don't include the file name itself
    Capybara.app = Rack::File.new('spec/factories/submission_stubs')
  end

  it 'loads the file' do
    visit 'mystub.html'

    puts page.body
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't stub the response the browser sees from your tests using WebMock since it only stubs local requests. To stub/mock responses to browser requests you should be looking at a programmable proxy like https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy